# Using loop in the Visual flow

Tags: visual-flows

Actually I am new to visual flow and got strike up in one of the requirement .Could you please help in this ..it will be great helpfull ..

Can we show more than one record in the single screen by default one record will show in single screen but i want to show three record in same screen without choose any further screen .

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a Dynamic Choice.  You can use that on a picklist or checkbox on your screen.  Not sure your use-case.  If you need more than just one name, create a custom field formula to concatenate the fields into one string.  Then you can see more data inside your Dynamic Choice.